# android facebook sdk (4.20) integration

Tags: android

I am updating facebook integration code for my project because facebook Graph API will be deprecate for my current facebook sdk this month. I am using `https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk` facebook sdk.

After integration I am able to get

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
project.group = 'com.facebook.android'

dependencies {
// Facebook Dependencies
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'

// Connected Tests
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
    targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'

    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

def isSnapshot = version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')
def ossrhUsername = hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
def ossrhPassword = hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""

task setVersion {
// The version will be derived from source
project.version = null
def sdkVersionFile = file('src/main/java/com/facebook/FacebookSdkVersion.java')
sdkVersionFile.eachLine{
    def matcher = (it =~ /(?:.*BUILD = \")(.*)(?:\".*)/)
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        project.version = matcher[0][1]
        return
    }
}
if (project.version.is('unspecified')) {
    throw new GradleScriptException('Version could not be found.', null)
}
}

uploadArchives {
repositories.mavenDeployer {
    beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

    repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
        authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
    }

    snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
        authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
    }

    pom.project {
        name 'Facebook-Android-SDK'
        artifactId = 'facebook-android-sdk'
        packaging 'aar'
        description 'Facebook Android SDK'
        url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'

        scm {
            connection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
            developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
            url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'
        }

        licenses {
            license {
                name 'Facebook Platform License'
                url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/LICENSE.txt'
                distribution 'repo'
            }
        }

        developers {
            developer {
                id 'facebook'
                name 'Facebook'
            }
        }
    }
}
}

uploadArchives.dependsOn(setVersion)

signing {
required { !isSnapshot && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
sign configurations.archives
}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
// JDK 1.8 is more strict then 1.7. Have JDK 1.8 behave like 1.7 for javadoc generation
if (org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().getJavaVersion() == JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8) {
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
}
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
classifier = 'javadoc'
from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
classifier = 'sources'
from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
archives androidSourcesJar
archives androidJavadocsJar
}

afterEvaluate {
androidJavadocs.classpath += project.android.libraryVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath
}
```

Comment: Please post your Gradle settings in your question.

Comment: @Raptor done...

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah, but not able to find any solution. Already have done code same as they have mentioned for gradle file.

Comment: Are you sure? I did not see `compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'` on that page.

Comment: Anyways, nothing I see here says the Graph API is deprecated. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads